# Android Studio fbc Live Template

Tags: android, android-studio, findviewbyid

`fbc` live template can be used as described here:

[android studio: how to use the fbc live template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393376/android-studio-how-to-use-the-fbc-live-template)

But this is very long and time-consuming process. Also, the change described in the answer will create default variable name e.g. textView for TextView object and we again have to rename it. So again, this takes more time than expected and unnecessary cursor movement.

How to use `fbc` in a more efficient way such that it requires less key strokes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this by making only a small change in fbc live template.

**Make a change in template:**

Press `Ctrl + Shift + A`

Select Live Templates Settings

[image]

Select `fbc` under Android and click on `Change` and make sure that `Statement` and `Expression` are checked. Then, click OK.

[image]

**Use the template:**

Declare your variable:

```
TextView myVar;
```

write your variable name which you can do pretty fast using code completion and assign fbc and then

```
myVar = fbc + <TAB>
```

this would expand to

```
myVar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.);
```

Now, press TAB, select id and press TAB. You are done.